# Get post author image - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress I need to fetch the Author image of author who created post. I tried to get the profile image in this way, but it didn't work.

Here is the code I have written to get other author_meta_details.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="avatar col-md-3">
        <picture class="avatar-circle">
            <?php if($avatar = get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID')) !== FALSE): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" alt="">
            <?php else: ?>
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/lymited-child/images/avatar-image.png">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="author-details col-md-9">
        <div class="author-name"><strong><?php echo get_the_author_meta('first_name'); ?></strong> - <?php echo get_the_author_meta('nickname'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="author-summery"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
   $get_author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
   $get_author_gravatar = get_avatar_url($get_author_id, array('size' => 450));

   if(has_post_thumbnail()){
      the_post_thumbnail();
   } else {
      echo '<img src="'.$get_author_gravatar.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />';
   }
?>
```

OR Remove this if the condition and try

```
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID') );
```

Comment: Can you please upvote to my answer so others can easily find it.@Mayuri

Answer (score 0):

`get_avatar()` returns `<img>` element so you don't need to wrap it to `img` again
Also you need to wrap `$avatar = ...` to parenthesis as `=` priority is lower than `!==`

try to replace this

```
<?php if ( $avatar = get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID')) !== FALSE): ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" alt="">
```

with this

```
<?php if ( ( $avatar = get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID')) ) !== FALSE): ?>
    <?php echo $avatar; ?>
```

Comment: Fixed an answer